# How to calculate this op-amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

[image]

I can see: Ic2A Pin1 is **V1=Vref-Id*R25**

where Vref = Vcc*R24/(R24+R23)

Id is the current flow through the D6 which is a photodiode.

Question is: **How to calculate the final output of Ic2B Pin7**

Comment: You can't calculate it because IC2B is used as an integrator and it's probably in some feedback system of which your circuit doesn't provide information on.

Comment: I don't think so.even as an intergrator there is a formula which can describe the relatioship between the input and the output